# Can I tempt the police into using a password that would destroy evidence without being guilty of destruction of evidence?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, evidence

Purely hypothetical situation here, not at all related to my need to hide my plans for world domination on my laptop...honest!!  Lets say I have incriminating evidence saved electronically somewhere.  I have a password which will let me into the data, but the tool I'm using to access it also has a failsafe which would instead erase the data if a different, dummy, password was used.

Now lets say the police have gotten a warrant to confiscate my computer or otherwise try to access my encrypted data, but they need a password to get in.  I'm guessing the police IT folks first back up everything on a disk before doing anything else which would potentially render my theoretical failsafe futile (but still leaving me guilty of attempting to destroy evidence which I suspect is still a crime...), but for now lets ignore that and pretend using my dummy password really would destroy all evidence.

I'm assuming if I tell the police officers my password is "I'mAnIdiot" and the data is erased as a result I'm guilty of destroying evidence since I knowingly set into motion action to have it destroyed?

However, what if I instead tempt them to type it without explicitly telling them to.  So two examples I could think of.

1. in a phone call I presume they would record I tell my supposed accomplice my password is "I'mAnIdiot", but never tell them to use it.
2. I leave a password written on a notepad somewhere near my computer so they will presume I wrote down my password, like an idiot.

If I actually managed to get the police to destroy evidence by trying either of the listed methods am I guilty of destroying evidence?  In short how indirect would one's actions have to be before one couldn't make a basis for intentional destruction of evidence?

If/where state laws are relevant I'll accept any state you have details on.

Comment: Intent matters.  Is it your intent in this scheme that evidence be destroyed, or are you acting with reckless disregard for that possibility?